# Order a python dictionary by length of item using OrderedDict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sorting, ordereddictionary

Im trying to use OrderedDict to make a dictionary where the item is a list of entries, and I want the ordering to be based on the length of the item list.

say for:

```
d = {2:[1], 1:[1,2,3], 4:[1,2], 5:[1,2,3,4]}
```

I tried:

```
od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(len(d.items())))
```

but I got a `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

I found a workaround by iterating something like this:

```
for k in sorted(d, key=lambda k: len(d[k]), reverse=True):
```

when needed, but I'd rather the dict be sorted beforehand.

Comment: The first `sorted` function call is wrong (the second is also wrong, but for different reasons) - and the error message explains why. The error has nothing to do with turning it back into an OrderedDictionary. Break the problem down into parts, fix the broken part, and then use/apply the corrections.

Comment: what do you mean by *I'd rather the dict be sorted beforehand.*?

Answer (score 3):

You could [sort `d.items()` according to the length of the values](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Key_Functions):

```
In [268]: sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)
Out[268]: [(5, [1, 2, 3, 4]), (1, [1, 2, 3]), (4, [1, 2]), (2, [1])]
```

and pass that to `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
In [267]: collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True))
Out[267]: OrderedDict([(5, [1, 2, 3, 4]), (1, [1, 2, 3]), (4, [1, 2]), (2, [1])])
```